# I need modelsim to look at inner variables

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, test-bench

I have VHDL code with INs , OUTs and inner SIGNAL constants such as counters that I want to simulate. I have looked at examples on the web and I only see Modelsim monitoring the INs and OUTs. However, I would also like to look at internal signals such as a counter. I saw one guy writing only simulation code. I need a simple example of the following: A code with some INs and OUTs and some internal signals. A simple universal TB code with just a clk increment or similar. I saw a sample that looked correct but when I adapted it to my code, the internal signals were undefined in Modelsim. I could be missing something but my understanding is that one important feature of Modelsim is writing a generic test-bench with a clock and using it to view a histogram of my logic. As your code progresses, you would only have to add variables as needed to the tb. If anyone had some generic code or location of the code in both original and tb, they would share would be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never had a problem getting modelsim to plot internal signals onto the waveforms. I just drag and drop the signal from the "objects" window onto the Wave window.

[image]

Here is a simple example. This is TestModule.vhd:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity TestModule is
port (
          ip_sl_ClkIn                : in std_logic;
          ip_slv_InputVal            : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
          ip_sl_InputValid           : in std_logic;

          op_slv_OutputVal           : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
          op_sl_OutputValid          : out std_logic
);
end TestModule;


architecture Behavioral of TestModule is

  --==========================
  --== INTERNAL SIGNALS
  --==========================
  signal s_slv_InputNibbleSwap_1d : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => 'X');
  signal s_slv_Inverted_2d : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => 'X');

  signal s_sl_InputValid_1d : std_logic := '0';
  signal s_sl_InputValid_2d : std_logic := '0';

begin


   RegisterProc : process(ip_sl_ClkIn)
    begin
      if(rising_edge(ip_sl_ClkIn)) then

      --Clock Cycle 1:
      --=======================
      --Take the input and swap nibble locations
      s_slv_InputNibbleSwap_1d <= ip_slv_InputVal(3 downto 0) & ip_slv_InputVal(7 downto 4);
      s_sl_InputValid_1d       <= ip_sl_InputValid;

      --Clock Cycle 2:
      --=======================          
      --Invert the bits
      s_slv_Inverted_2d        <= not(s_slv_InputNibbleSwap_1d);
      s_sl_InputValid_2d       <= s_sl_InputValid_1d;

      end if; --rising_edge(ip_sl_ClkIn)
    end process RegisterProc;



    --Route Outputs:
    --=====================
    op_slv_OutputVal  <= s_slv_Inverted_2d;
    op_sl_OutputValid <= s_sl_InputValid_2d;

end Behavioral;
```

Here is the testbench, TestModule_tb.vhd:

```
 LIBRARY ieee;
  USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
  use std.textio.all;
ENTITY TestModule_tb IS
END TestModule_tb;

architecture behavior of TestModule_tb is

-- Component Declaration
-------------------------
  component TestModule
  Port ( 
        ip_sl_ClkIn : in std_logic;
        ip_slv_InputVal : in std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0 );
        ip_sl_InputValid : in std_logic;
        op_slv_OutputVal : out std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0 );
        op_sl_OutputValid : out std_logic
    );
  end component;



--Signals Driven by Entity: TestModule
-------------------------
    signal s_slv_OutputVal : std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0 );
    signal s_sl_OutputValid : std_logic;


--Test Stimulus Signals:
-------------------------
    signal s_sl_ClkIn : std_logic;
    signal s_slv_InputVal : std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0 );
    signal s_sl_InputValid : std_logic;


BEGIN

--Component Instantiation
    uut : TestModule
    Port Map (
        ip_sl_ClkIn         => s_sl_ClkIn   ,  --in std_logic
        ip_slv_InputVal     => s_slv_InputVal   ,  --in std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0 )
        ip_sl_InputValid    => s_sl_InputValid   ,  --in std_logic
        op_slv_OutputVal    => s_slv_OutputVal   ,  --out std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0 )
        op_sl_OutputValid   => s_sl_OutputValid     --out std_logic
    );


    clkProc : process
    begin
        s_sl_ClkIn <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        s_sl_ClkIn <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
    end process;


MainTestProcess : Process
Begin

     s_slv_InputVal <= (others => '0');
     s_sl_InputValid <= '0';
     wait for 100 ns; 

     wait until rising_edge(s_sl_ClkIn); wait for 1 ps;
     s_slv_InputVal <= X"AB";
     s_sl_InputValid <= '1';

     wait until rising_edge(s_sl_ClkIn); wait for 1 ps;
     s_slv_InputVal <= X"FF";
     s_sl_InputValid <= '0';     

     wait for 100 ns;

    --Not a failure, but stops the simulation
    assert false report "<---- NOT a failure. Testbench Complete" severity failure;

    wait; -- Will wait forever
end process;

END;
```

Here is a modelsim DO file for compiling and simulating, TestModule_tb.do:

```
vlib work
vcom -reportprogress 300 -work work TestModule.vhd
vcom -reportprogress 300 -work work TestModule_tb.vhd 
vsim -gui work.testmodule_tb
do TestModule_tb_wave.do
run -all
```

And here is the modelsim waveform DO file, TestModule_tb_wave.do:

```
onerror {resume}
quietly WaveActivateNextPane {} 0
add wave -noupdate /testmodule_tb/uut/ip_sl_ClkIn
add wave -noupdate /testmodule_tb/uut/ip_slv_InputVal
add wave -noupdate /testmodule_tb/uut/ip_sl_InputValid
add wave -noupdate /testmodule_tb/uut/op_slv_OutputVal
add wave -noupdate /testmodule_tb/uut/op_sl_OutputValid
add wave -noupdate /testmodule_tb/uut/s_slv_InputNibbleSwap_1d
add wave -noupdate /testmodule_tb/uut/s_slv_Inverted_2d
add wave -noupdate /testmodule_tb/uut/s_sl_InputValid_1d
add wave -noupdate /testmodule_tb/uut/s_sl_InputValid_2d
TreeUpdate [SetDefaultTree]
WaveRestoreCursors {{Cursor 1} {90738 ps} 0}
quietly wave cursor active 1
configure wave -namecolwidth 331
configure wave -valuecolwidth 100
configure wave -justifyvalue left
configure wave -signalnamewidth 0
configure wave -snapdistance 10
configure wave -datasetprefix 0
configure wave -rowmargin 4
configure wave -childrowmargin 2
configure wave -gridoffset 0
configure wave -gridperiod 1
configure wave -griddelta 40
configure wave -timeline 0
configure wave -timelineunits ps
update
WaveRestoreZoom {0 ps} {231001 ps}
```

Comment: I have a program, call it prog.vhd. I also have prog_tb.vhd. The main has about 20 INs/OUTs and 10 signals. When I run Modelsim, I only get the INs/OUTs. I am having trouble getting the internals to the Simulate section. After some perturbations, I got a signal to transfer to the Simulation. However, the signal was undefined. There is something I am missing. I would like to learn by an example code.

Comment: I have modified my answer to show an example of using modelsim to look at internal signals.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now think I understand the format of a test bench file with internal signals. I will work on it some tonight but it is already beer:30 here in North Carolina.

Comment: I finally got Modelsim looking at all variables. Now, this leads to another issue. If I have a large variable, say 200 bits, how would one look at only a group of these bits, say (20-28)?

Comment: There are a couple ways to do that. You could create a new signal in your VHDL code that assigns bits 20-28 and look at that new signal in modelsim. You can also do this in modelsim directly: in the wave window, expand your 200 bit vector, and select the bits you would like to view on their own (click the first bit and then hold shift and click the second), then you can right click and select "Combine Signal" and give it a new name, and it will display a new signal with just those bits. If I answered you original question, please "accept" as the answer.